# How to time and benchmark Bigquery Standard SQL scripts?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, performance-testing, code-readability, timeit

I have different versions of the Bigquery Standard scripts i.e. I follow the Standard API [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators). I am trying to find out Matlab-style timeit or warmed-up timing measures to benchmark different scripts:

*Version A: very readabled code with modular code*

```
WITH a AS
(
SELECT * FROM SOURCE
), 
a_ AS
(
SELECT ... FROM a
)
SELECT * FROM a_
```

*Version B: very unreadable code with subqueries but claimed to be efficient*

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM SOURCE))
```

**How can I time and benchmark different Standard SQL queries in Google Bigquery?**

*Possible perspectives to address*

> 1. Do I need to warm up BQ Standard SQL queries like in Matlab?
> 2. What are the common performance differences between the version A and B? Any Pros and Cons? How can you demonstrate that in Bigquery?
> 3. Any documentation or recommendations available for the two different approaches (overusing subqueries vs modular coding)?

Comment: check https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant did I miss it or did this article address anything about modular coding style (A) vs subqueries style (B)? I understand the filtering which you can achieve with both approaches. Also, I could not find any benchmark options.

Comment: the reason I referenced this article is that understanding `query plan explanation` helps to understand what is happening under the hood in BigQuery - no matter how fancy and [un]readable sometime we write the query.

Comment: Readability <> Performance. Why do you think there will be a difference in performance? Common Table Expressions (CTEs) are not a performance oriented feature. In the manner you have described your query variants A and B there is strong likelihood an optimizer will interpret the queries with the same query plan. Using explain will help you understand if the query variants are  executed in the same manner or not.

Comment: CTEs <> Readability improvement. Readability is inherently subjective,. Personally I detest reading SQL queries that have employed CTEs purely for "readability" because all it promotes is sequential thinking. Traditional subqueries are much closer to the "set based" nature of  SQL and with familiarity and good formatting are highly "readable" anyway.

Comment: @Mikhail do non-empty values, apparently NULL, take any space? So can I filter fields w `IF(..., Val1, NULL)` instead of where in subqueries? Relevant? `"Cloud Bigtable tables are sparse. Empty columns don't take up any space. As a result, it often makes sense to create a very large number of columns, even if most columns are empty in most rows"`? https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/schema-design

Comment: @Used so CTEs/subqueries choice matters to performance optimisation? But is prefiltering more important so can you optimise more efficiently by early IFs in fields before assigning them or filtering with WHEREs?

Comment: No. That is the inverse of what I tried to convey.  You can take almost any subquery and make it a cte,  or vice versa take the type of ctes in your question and make it a subquery.  The net effect it most likely to be zero or unmeasurable.

Answer (score 0):

*I summarires the comments and I recite on the speedup opportunities from the perspective of costs.*

---

A demonstrates CTE (Common Table Expressions) while B demonstrates construction with subqueries like sets. The user Used_By_Already commentted that the difference should not matter in the performance so not convey speedup opportunities.

> *"No. That is the inverse of what I tried to convey. You can take almost any subquery and make it a cte, or vice versa take the type of ctes in your question and make it a subquery. The net effect it most likely to be zero or unmeasurable."*

What matters is the prefiltering, more [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-plan-explanation) as forwarded by Mikhail Berlyant in a comment. So you can make your queries more efficient by prefiltering data early.

As a side note, more early filtering and hence less computation may not affect on charging, more [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing), because charging is based on the input data, not on the amount of computation. So query optimisation for speedup opportunity makes little sense in Bigquery in terms of monetary costs, even though you may save some time.